# Trying to add a NAS to Plex in Ubuntu

Tags: mount, nas

I have been trying Ubuntu occasionally now and decided to start use Ubuntu for my plex server instead of windows.

I have a nas where all data is stored and have tried to auto mount it using fstab. 
Set the folling setting in fstab:

```
//192.168.0.20/plex /media/Plex cifs credentials=/home/josef/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

The thing is that when I click on it after a reboot it says I don’t have root privileges so I run

```
sudo Mount -a
```

which adds the share. However I still can’t view it due since I don’t have Permission.

I have tried chown but it makes no difference.

What can I do?

This is how the smb.conf-file looks:

```
[plexmedia]
comment = Plex Media Files
path = /mnt/data/officeshared
create mask = 0775
writeable = yes
force user = plex
force group = plex
valid users = josef, admin, plex
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in on the side of the NAS provider.  You'll have to configure **rw** permission from the file server.

Your credentials file (in this case `/home/josef/.smbcredentials`) will have to have an entry similar to:

```
username=userID
password=password
```

This entry **userID** has to be a userID that is on your NAS server.  The password will have to match the password configured on the server for that user.

The NAS server share configuration will have to be configured for **read/write** permission for that userID (the userID that is on the server).

Tell the NAS system administrator to provide you with a user/password for read/write permission.  If you (which is most likely) have administration access to the NAS server, that configures the NAS server for a userID with `rw` permissions.

If the NAS server is Ubuntu running Samba this entry would work:

```
[plexmedia]
        comment = Plex Media Files
        path = /mnt/data/officeshared
        create mask = 0775
        writeable = yes
        browseable = yes
        force user = plex
        force group = plex
        valid users = userid, user1, user2
```

From the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` entry above, the valid users (`userid`, `user1`, `user2`) would have the permissions provided in this setting.

For Windows, the settings are using done via mouse click GUI.  You can look at [How to Share and Set Permissions for Folders and Files Using Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456988.aspx) steps in setting the permissions on a Windows NAS server.

Comment: Thanks so far! I presume I set the valid users to be my username? It didn't work however, and yes I am administrator of the NAS. I log in as the administrator so i have all read/write permissions. But it seems as my local Linux-user doesn't have persmissions?

Comment: The valid users doesn't have to be your username, but it can be.  It'll have to be the username that you are giving `rw` access to.  When you connect to the Share, connect using the username that has read/write access.  Use that username and password in your `crendential's` file.

Comment: There is one username for Ubuntu. It’s in the smb.conf. In the smbcredentials I have the login for the Nas. Admin-user.

Comment: To program the NAS server, the username that you are giving access to has to exist on the server.  Give `rw` access to that server.  Then put the username and password in the credentials file.  It sounds like your NAS server is Ubuntu.  If that's the case and you post the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` block of your `/media/plex` entry, I could probably tell you exactly where your read/write problems lie.  Using the example in my answer would work for the users `userid`, `user`, and `user2`.

Comment: My NAS-server is a Synology DS215j, I believe it has a Linux-system, but not specifically Ubuntu. I will try to look into this when I get home again... Thanks for your helps so far, much appreciated!

Comment: This is how it looks in my smb.conf file      [plexmedia]
 comment = Plex Media Files
 path = /mnt/data/officeshared
 create mask = 0775
 writeable = yes
 force user = plex
 force group = plex
 valid users = josef, admin, plex

Comment: @l-d-james Did you have any reply to my last comment?

Comment: Would you mind editing your question and placing configuration block there so that I can review it in a formatted manner?  If there's a discrepancy it'll make it substantially easier to realize the culprit.

Comment: Hello! Sorry, i fixed it now. Question edited

Comment: Are you saying your issue is resolved.  If you are saying that, please consider giving back to the community by showing which answers has helped by clicking on the uparrow to upvote, showing the message has merit, and/or clicking the gray checkmark.

Comment: No its not solved. I added the code as a configuration block. Sorry about that. Still waiting for someone to help

Comment: It'll probably take about 5 messages apiece to identify where you're going wrong.  One message a week would have it resolved in about two months.  If the responses came quicker it could be resolved in one day.  I'm glad to help and don't mind waiting for your convenience to response.  But keep in mind, most of the waiting is for your response to details needed.  From the block you have provided, you have given full access to the users `josef`, `admin`, and `plex`.  Do those users have full `read/write` access to the files and folders on the server? (continued...)

Comment: (... continued)  You have a `smbcredentials` file.  Does the userID in your crendentials file have `read/write` access to the shared files on the server?  That is what is necessary for you to have full `read/write` access from the client end.  If the credential's ID doesn't have full access to the files on the server, the client can't override what is available on the server.  So at present I'll need a response to those two questions.

Comment: Hi, it wasn’t meant as criticism. I can see now that it seems so. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes the admin user has full access t the synology-NAS and is the user set up in smbcredentials.conf.

Comment: I didn't take it as a criticism.  I took it as a misunderstanding on your part.  You mentioned waiting for assistance.  I was pointing out a method for you to expedite the process.

Comment: The user Plex and Josef does not have full access even though the user Plex has full access to the mounted folder. The user Josef is the local user on Ubuntu.

Comment: I used `officeshared` as an example of how to configure a shared block in samba.  I took the example from one of my servers.  Looking at what you have in your question, you are mounting `/media/Plex` for your media.  However, you are giving permission to a resource called `/mnt/data/officeshared`.  You will have to start off by matching the `smb.conf` block with the same resource you are mounting `/media/Plex`.  Also make sure that the particular folder that you are trying to write to is owned by a `valid user` that have full  `write` access.

Comment: At present, what you have in your question won't work because the folder you are mounting: `/plex` doesn't match the folder you are sharing `/mnt/data/officeshared`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68256/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-trying-to-add-a-nas-to-plex-in-ubuntu).